# is there any way to forcefully imply validation on update_all

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a Rails application I am using `update_all` to updates but as we know it is skipping the validations how can I forcefully apply validation on this `update_all`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Running validations when using \`update\_all\`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39644646/running-validations-when-using-update-all)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [API docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Relation.html#method-i-update_all) *(emphasis my own)*.

> Updates all records with details given if they match a set of conditions supplied, limits and order can also be supplied. This method constructs a single SQL UPDATE statement and sends it straight to the database. **It does not instantiate the involved models and it does not trigger Active Record callbacks or validations.**

No, there is not a way to force validations when calling `update_all`. The purpose of `update_all` is to modify records in bulk **without instantiating model instances for each record**. A model instance must exist for a record to have validations called against it.

Comment: Thanks to you ........I have to then use a hook to check the validation will it be a good way for this

Comment: you can however, create not-null or unique-constraints in your database (for pg see http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/ddl-constraints.html), but this is not the "rails way"...