# Running validations when using `update_all`

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, activerecord

According to the Rails docs [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#skipping-validations) and [here](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Relation/update_all), using `update_all` does not do the following -

- It skips validations
- It does not update the `updated_at` field
- It silently ignores the `:limit` and `:order` methods

I'm trying to go through my code base and remove instances of `update_all`, particularly because of the first point.

Is there a way to still have the convenience of `update_all` and still run validations? I understand that I can loop through each record and save it, but that's not only messier visually but also more more inefficient because it executes N SQL statements instead of 1

```
# before
User.where(status: "active").update_all(status: "inactive")
# after
User.where(status: "active").each { |u| u.update(status: "inactive") }
```

Thanks!

**Edit:** I'm using Rails 4.2

Comment: You probably want to look into [batches](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Batches.html)

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Unfortunately `update_all` is way faster because it doesn't instantiate an active record object for each record and instead deals directly with the database.  In your case, since you need validations and callbacks, you'll need to instantiate the objects and so you're best bet is iterating in batches of 1000 and performing the update as originally shown.  Such as:

```
User.where(status: "active").find_each { |u| u.update(status: "inactive") }
```

The `find_each` method only loads 1000 objects at a time thus not overloading the garbage collector.  If you have bulk records in the hundreds of thousands of rows I'd consider going back to update_all or moving the updating to a background task since it can easily cause a timeout when deployed.

Comment: Why you're using thousands of query instead of single query? Is this reason just for Rubocop error?

Comment: OP needs to loop because of validations so it's best to loop in batches where the GC wipes the objects in memory from past iterations instead of holding all records in memory at once.