# Rubocop command to disable Rails/SkipsModelValidations: avoid using update_all error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubocop

I want to change one column to `is_deleted: true` in my records by below line:

```
UserTag.where(cms_tag_id: webhook.dig('entity', 'id')).update_all(is_deleted: true)
```

But I'm getting Rubocop's error:

`Rails/skipsmodelvalidations: avoid using update_all because it skips validations.`

I know I can use each block and update all columns through e.update in a block but `update_all` is much faster, one line, neat solution.

How to disable such a rubocop error only for this, specific line?

Comment: As a possible alternative to having to disable Rubocop rules: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39644646/running-validations-when-using-update-all

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can run the below command, which will generate a .rubocop_todo.yml file which will record and ignore specific offences for offending files:

```
rubocop --auto-gen-config --exclude-limit 999 --no-offense-counts
```

`--auto-gen-config` generates the yml file, the only non-optional flag to achieve what you are looking for.

`--exclude-limit xxx` is a number of offence before rubocop disables the check for the entire application.

`--no-offense-counts` does not record a count how many offences there are in the yml file.

Ensure you've thought about the consequences of ignoring linters; it is usually ill advised to not follow the linter advice. Be aware that this will disable checks for all offences in the spec tests.

**Update**

If you want to disable rubocop checks without generating a file, you can use a comment like so:

```
Company.where(cms_tag_id: webhook.dig('entity', 'id')).update_all(is_deleted: true) # rubocop:disable Rails/SkipsModelValidations
```

Comment: Honestly I don't want to create new file for just a single line. I think there is some kind of one line disable function, the syntax would be like `UserTag.where(..).update_all(...) #some rubocop disable command`. But I don't know what that command is for such an action.

Answer (score 5):

To expand on @benjessop's answer:
To disable RuboCop selectively for a block of code, use `# rubocop:disable` ... `# rubocop:enable` block, like so:

```
# rubocop:disable Rails::SkipsModelValidations

# The specified cop is not enforced here.
# Therefore, make this block of code minimal. 
# For example, just this one line:

UserTag.where(cms_tag_id: webhook.dig('entity', 'id')).update_all(is_deleted: true)

# rubocop:enable Rails::SkipsModelValidations
```

**SEE ALSO:**

[Disabling Cops within Source Code](https://docs.rubocop.org/rubocop/configuration.html#disabling-cops-within-source-code)
More general info on [RuboCop Configuration](https://docs.rubocop.org/rubocop/configuration.html)